# Combine jpg frames into high quality gif

Tags: unix, gif, jpeg, imagick

I need to convert some jpg frames into high quality gif. I know about imagick but its taking to much and uses a lot of resources. A fast way its gifsicle but it only supports 256 colors.

I know that gif supports 265 colors but imagick uses colormaps (i think) and delivers a higher quality than gifscile.

Btw, it also needs to support custom frame animation delay.

For imagick i am using:

```
convert -loop 0 -resize 400x337 -quality 100% *.jpg result.gif
```

There are about 24 frames, each frame about 700Kb

Comment: The example you posted is using Imagemagick with the command line and you want to use Imagick that is built into php? There was a post in the last couple of weeks about different frame delays on different images using Imagick and it has not had a reply yet and so it might not be available.

Comment: @Bonzo - i am interested in command line, not php :)

Comment: Sorry but you mentioned Imagick which is an Imagemagick php API. Anyway I have not had anything to do with gif animations but you can find some useful information here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#gif_anim There are two other pages there about animations as well.

Answer (score 0):

For really high quality there's [gifski encoder](https://gif.ski/), which combines frames to achieve more than 256 colors per frame. However, it's not as fast as gifsicle and it only supports PNG frames, not JPEG (JPEG is a really bad idea for GIF input, since compression artefacts will add lots of wasted colors to the image).